# Changing the marker of the OpenStreetMap in the Directorist (dservice) theme on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, openstreetmap

I am currently trying to change the marker of the OpenStreetMap in the Directorist (dservice) theme on wordpress.

I tried changing the css code by accessing the corresponding files in the wp-content folder.
But even by using "!important" on specific parts of the code the output is not changing.
I would like to replace the marker which currently just a styled div into a png image.

I searched online for tutorials but I could'nt find any satisfying response.

Hoping any of you, could provide some informations :).
Have a nice day,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.